# IF/ELSE statement validation issue

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
View.OnClickListener calcu = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        double q;
        String d = "";
        double factor = cpi[to] / cpi [from];
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
        if (eNum.getText().toString().length() <= 0 || bFrom.getText() == "- Select a Year -" || bTo.getText() == "- Select a Year -") {
            if (eNum.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                d += "Enter Dollar Amount";
                eNum.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            if (bFrom.getText() == "- Select a Year -") {
                d += "Select a Year";
                bFrom.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            if (bTo.getText() == "- Select a Year -") {
                d += "Select a Year";
                bTo.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
        else {
            dollarAmount = factor * Double.parseDouble(eNum.getText().toString());
            String value = Double.toString(dollarAmount);
            if (value.charAt(value.length() - 2) == '.') {
                value += "0";
            }
            displayToast("Dollar: " + value);

            if (cpi[to] != cpi[from]) {
                double f, y;
                if (cpi[to] > cpi[from]) {
                    f = cpi[to] / cpi [from];
                    y = to - from;
                }
                else {
                    f = cpi[from] / cpi[to];
                    y = from - to;
                }
                q = Math.pow(f, 1/y);
                q = (q-1)*100.0;
                q = Math.round(q*100.0)/100.0;
                displayToast("Inflation: " + String.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(q)));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

`displayToast()` is a function which displays the Toast message to the user.

`eNum` is an `EditText`

`bFrom` and `bTo` are `Buttons`

What I want to happen when the onClick method is activated:

1. If the `eNum` is empty, I want to make the text color RED.
2. If the `bFrom` and `bTo` buttons text is `- Select a Year -`, I want to make the text color RED.
3. If #1 and #2 is not true than display the Toasts.

**Right now when I click, nothing is happening**. How do I fix the above code to work correctly?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just checking, did you setOnClickListener(calcu) ?

Comment: 1) Use equals() instead of == when comparing String/Object.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Yes I did. Sorry forgot to post that part :)

Comment: Seriously, how many times has Java string comparison been asked on SO? Or in life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

`bFrom.getText() == "- Select a Year -"`

To this:

`bFrom.getText().equals("- Select a Year -")`

And the same would go for your `bTo.getText() == "- Select a Year -")` line.

Use `.equals()` to compare objects (e.g. Strings) and `==` for primitives

Answer (score 1):

If you are comparing string then you need to use .equals.

Comment: Yeah, but someone else already said the same thing an hour ago.

Comment: Correct. Just highlighted the problem he is facing.

Comment: @SachinM Thank you for the response and I appreciate it. Do not pay any mind to Dave Newton!